# Duplicate Dataframe rows based on join key

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

Lets say I have two dfs - teachers and departments

```
teacher_id, name, dep_id
1, ABC, 10
2, XYZ, 20
```

---

```
dep_id
10
20
40
50
```

I want to duplicate teachers rows for the missing departments. so the output needs to be:

```
teacher_id, name, dep_id
1, ABC, 10
1, ABC, 20
1, ABC, 40
1, ABC, 50
2, XYZ, 20
2, XYZ, 10
2, XYZ, 40
2, XYZ, 50
```

Outer Join and merges with pandas will put a NaN for teacher_id and name. I want to duplicate the values. Any ideas how to do this simple ?

Comment: @Ch3steR - Its not really a cartesian join. If I had an additional row in teachers for (1, ABC, 20), cartesian join will give 12 rows as 3 rows of teachers x 4 departments. The actual output is only 8 rows.

Comment: Understood now, thanks for clarifying. Posted an answer see if works for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`Groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with custom func which filters out missing `dep_id` then add them to respective `teacher_id` using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and use [`df.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

```
#df
#   teacher_id name  dep_id
#0           1  ABC      10
#1           2  XYZ      20

#df1
#   dep_id
#0      10
#1      20
#2      40
#3      50

def fill(df):
    m = df1['dep_id'].isin(df['dep_id'])
    missing = df1.loc[~m]
    return pd.concat([df, missing]).ffill()

df.groupby('teacher_id',group_keys=False).apply(fill)

   teacher_id name  dep_id
0         1.0  ABC      10
1         1.0  ABC      20
2         1.0  ABC      40
3         1.0  ABC      50
1         2.0  XYZ      20
0         2.0  XYZ      10
2         2.0  XYZ      40
3         2.0  XYZ      50
```